# How do I disable iTunes working from the shortcut keys?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, keyboard-shortcuts, spotify

I want to stop iTunes from responding to the shortcut keys i.e. F7, F8, F9 because I use Spotify.

So what happens is when I pause Spotify iTunes starts bouncing around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/05/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-grasp/) lifehacker offers one solution, though currently there is no real way to do this short of removing iTunes completely (you can just drag it to the trash can).

Comment: Strange that they don't allow it!

Comment: Eh, Apple's known for being draconian. Perhaps that is part of their key to success, perhaps that's just Steve Jobs being himself. We may never know!

Comment: Yeah I suppose but usually they won't sacrifice usability or user experience in the process.  

I mean like with Flash on the iPhone - they don't allow it but there are at least alternatives for watching video.

If they did this deliberately, that would just be plain stupid.

Comment: Well, they don't allow you to use 3rd party audio players fully, but there is at least an alternative - iTunes. I guess it's all about perspective, eh? This certainly wouldn't be the first case of vendor lock-in (and not that i'm condoning it, just playing devil's advocate).